# Are electrons bounded or unbounded to nuclei when they are degenerate?

Tags: astrophysics, fermions, fermi-energy, white-dwarfs

I have a question about degenerate electrons in white dwarfs.
So, as far as I know, when the gas contained in stars is compressed so much, the electrons start to fill the lowest energy level and then, for Pauli's Principle, they continue to fill up incresing energy levels up to a certain level.

As you can read here http://astro.vaporia.com/start/electrondegeneracy.html,
"*During compression, as electrons take on momentum, they gain too much to maintain a nucleus orbit, and they travel freely through the material rather than remain with a single nucleus.*"
I did not understand this last statement. Does this mean that the electron become free? Or they are still bounded to the nuclei?

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not bound. At white dwarf densities, a typical electron kinetic energy (0.6-0.8 times the Fermi Energy) is a few hundred to a few thousand keV. This is far too much for them to be bound to nuclei.

**Details:**

The Fermi momentum is given by
$$p_F = \left(\frac{3h^3 n}{8\pi}\right)^{1/3}\ , $$
where $n$ is the fermion number density.

The kinetic energy associated with the Fermi momentum is then
$$K = (p_F^2c^2 + m^2c^4)^{1/2} - mc^2\ , $$
where $m$ is the fermion rest mass.

This is the maximum kinetic energy of the electrons. The average kinetic energy is somewhere between 0.6 (non-relativistic limit, if $p_F \ll mc$) and 0.8 (relativistic limit, if $p_F \gg mc$) times the maximum.

If we take a typical white dwarf, made of carbon nuclei plus six electrons for each nucleus, the central densities reach $10^{10}$ kg/m$^3$. The electron number density is $n_e =\rho/2m_u = 3\times 10^{36}$ m$^{-3}$, where $m_u$ is an atomic mass unit and the 2 arises because there are two mass units for every electron in the gas.

Using the formulae above we get a maximum electron kinetic energy of 508 keV; the electrons are becoming relativistic, so the average electron kinetic energy is about 350 keV. This can be compared with the ionisation energy of the inner electron on a carbon nucleus of 490 eV.

More massive white dwarfs are denser, the Fermi momenta and average energies are larger.

If enough mass were added to the white dwarf, the maximum electron energy reaches about 14 MeV and it becomes possible for protons in the carbon nuclei to capture electrons to form neutrons (see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/387013/43351). This process removes free electrons and hence the source of pressure and leads to the detonation of the star in a thermonuclear type Ia supernova.

Answer (score -1):

Let me give a slightly longer answer than ProfRob.

The degenerate electrons in a star will behave quite like the degenerate sea of electrons in a metal. They are not bound to the nuclei, but instead see the whole macroscopic object's size as free to move in, except that they would bounce back at the surface of the object, star or metal.

This state of affairs continues until the pressures are so great, that the electrons start to transition from "tolerably described by non-relativisitic kinetic energy expression", to "have to be described by the relativistic part of the kinetic energy expression". This is important because the relativistic part produces less pressure contributions than the non-relativistic part. That means the electrons alone stop being able to really supply the pressure needed to keep the star stable.

And then the star will implode, converting almost all of its electrons and protons into neutrons, and let the neutrons generate the pressure needed to keep the new neutron star stable. This is an incredibly violent event, a supernova, and it will spill out a lot of material, the outer layers of the previously white dwarf star, and those material eventually become the iron in our blood, and gold that we collect.

Comment: The implosion of a white dwarf to form a neutron star has never been observed and is not thought to be how most of the iron and gold in the universe was created. Relativistic electron degeneracy pressure is greater than non-relativistic degeneracy pressure.

Comment: @ProfRob Wiki disagrees with you, agreeing with my basic astrophysics and statistical thermodynamics notes that relativistic electron degeneracy pressure is smaller than non-relativistic degeneracy pressure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrasekhar_limit

Comment: @ProfRob Under the physics section it says $P=K_1\rho^{5/3}$ and $P=K_2\rho^{4/3}$ respectively. The entire graph there is discussing this behaviour. Please stop this.

Comment: There is no graph of degeneracy pressure on the wiki page. Plots of degeneracy pressure versus density can be found anywhere. (For example https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/22373/what-is-the-condition-for-the-number-density-of-a-gas-to-be-ultra-relativistic-o ). The source of your confusion is that $K_2$ and $K_1$ are different (they don't even have the same units). Relativistic degeneracy pressure is obviously far higher than non-relativistic degeneracy pressure for the same fermions.

Comment: @ProfRob The point is that the slower growth rate makes it unable to stop, as opposed to the non-relativistic case. It is very obvious that $K_1\neq K_2$, as you mentioned, and in fact, there must be a constant shifting term too.

Comment: The current understanding is that white dwarfs do not implode. A white dwarf that becomes unstable *ignites* before it can implode, and the resulting fusion of He, C, and O into Fe releases sufficient energy to unbind the star, producing a type Ia supernova. It's the cores of giant stars that are thought to collapse to neutron stars and black holes.

Comment: That's nice. I'm happy to be corrected this way.